# How to load an image from ImageField of all instances of a model

Tags: python, django

So I have an app called todo, a Good model with ImageField. In my template I want to iterate over all instances of Good model and display all instances' images which were uploaded by admin in admin panel but when I try to run the code below I get:
Not Found: /todo/static/goods_images/image_2023-04-03_224219080.png
[04/Apr/2023 00:22:26] "GET /todo/static/goods_images/image_2023-04-03_224219080.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2355

model.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Good(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.FloatField()
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='todo/goods_images', null=True, blank=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-price']
    
    def __str__ (self):
        return str(self.name)
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import Good

class GoodsList(ListView):
    model = Good
    context_object_name = 'goods'
    template_name = 'goods_list.html'
```

goods_list.html:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
    
    {% for good in goods %}
    <div>
        {{ good.pic }}
        <img src="{{ good.pic.url }}" />
        {{ good.name }}
        {{ good.price }}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    
    
</html>
```

settings.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import GoodsList
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


    
urlpatterns = [
    path('goods_list/', GoodsList.as_view()),
]

if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Already went through a couple of videos but all of them load as static only one image and so in template write the exact path to it but in my case I iterate over all instances of model to gotta use variables in the template

Comment: The images uploaded in ImageFields are not uploaded to static but to media folder. Can you share the part of your settings.py with the MEDIA_ROOT, MEDIA_URL, STATIC_URL etc, it seems you have a problem at this level because right now your images are saved in medias but for any reason the display try to get them from static

Comment: 'STATIC_URL = 'static/'

in my settings.py only this option is specified

Answer (score 0):

It's weird you don't have these settings made by Django on the project creation but here is what you need in your settings:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/' # Part of the url your server will understand as a static file request
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'# Part of the url your server will understand as a media file request
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static", # Adding the root static folder (if not set all the statics have to be in the apps)
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_assets') # Path to the folder where your static will be assembled on deployment in production (useless in dev)
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # Path to the folder where the uploaded files will be saved.
```

Now when you uplaod your files they will go in the folder medias in the subfolders specified in your "upload_to" attribute.

And finally put this:

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

in your urls in place of this:

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

To activate the access to your medias in dev

Comment: so did all that u said + created static and media folder (media one with a subfolder mathing the upload_to argument) in my project folder. but still when i go to specified previously url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/goods_list/
gat errors and no images are displayed:

Not Found: /media/todo/goods_images/image_2023-04-04_010833280.png
[04/Apr/2023 01:13:05] "GET /media/todo/goods_images/image_2023-04-04_010833280.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2352

Comment: The good thing is, it goes to pick it at the good place. Can you check that the image is present in the directory, be sure of the naming of your different directories Can you share the settings part about statics and medias

Comment: Yeah, all the images I add through admin panel are saved in the correct directory but still getting that 404 error. In my setting just added what u said:

Comment: `
import os
STATIC_URL = '/static/' 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static", 
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_assets') 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 
`

Comment: and now have the following in my urls:
`if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

Comment: Is your image displayed in the admin?

Comment: No, I guess.
well in the admin near the imagefield it shows the current path of an image. 
like this: 
Currently: todo/goods_images/image_2023-04-04_010833280.png

but when i try to go to this link it shows me Page not found (404) because the url that this link have didn’t match any of listed in urls.py it says

Comment: I added img_preview field in admin panel and still my image doesn't show. (added this field through mark_safe() ). So yeah it doesn't display in the admin

Comment: Can you check in the database the value of the field?